# Is it a good idea to overcharge a method?

Tags: javascript, overloading

I have 3 classes, all extend the previous one.
Entity -> Body -> Player
Each one has a `die()` method which do very different things.
`Entity.die()` will call the db
`Body.die()` will animate the body
`Player.die()` will call the UI and play special sound.

I don't want to manually call `Entity.die()` inside `Body.die` method, mainly because I have many classes and many common methods and I don't want to forget something.

I wrote this little piece of code which does exactly this, the Error stack is easy to understand and points to the correct lines.

```
function overLoadMethods (parent, children) {
  const methods = {}
  for (let [fname, fn] of Object.entries(parent)) {
    if (typeof fn === 'function') {
      if (children[fname]) {
        methods[fname] = function () {
          fn()
          children[fname]()
        }
        Object.defineProperty(methods[fname], 'name', { value: fname })
      } else {
        methods[fname] = fn
      }
    }
  }
  return methods
}

function createEntity () {
  return {
    die: () => {
      console.log(new Error().stack)
      console.log('entity die')
    }
  }
}

const bodyMethods = {
  die: () => {
    console.log(new Error().stack)
    console.log('body die')
  }
}

function createBody () {
  const entity = createEntity()
  const overLoadedMethods = overLoadMethods(entity, bodyMethods)
  return {
    ...entity,
    ...bodyMethods,
    ...overLoadedMethods
  }
}

const playerMethods = {
  die: () => {
    console.log(new Error().stack)
    console.log('player die')
  }
}

function createPlayer () {
  const body = createBody()
  const overLoadedMethods = overLoadMethods(body, playerMethods)
  return {
    ...body,
    ...playerMethods,
    ...overLoadedMethods
  }
}

const player = createPlayer()
// will call Entity.die() then Body.die() then Player.die()
player.die()
```

Everything is working fine but I never saw this pattern before and I guess there is a good reason which I'm unaware of.
Could someone point the weakness of this pattern if there is one (pretty sure there is) ?

Comment: Your title says "overcharge" - that term doesn't exist. There is over**load** and over**ride**. Method overloading refers to having methods with the same name but different signature, e.g., `myMethod()` and `myMethod(var1)` and `myMethod(var1, var2)` would be overloads. JS doesn't really have an overloading mechanism, as it doesn't differentiate signatures, it only looks at the name. Overriding is when you have the *same* method name and signature. In this case the new method replaces the previous one, e.g., `parent.myMethod()` can be overriden by `child.myMethod()`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer it *might* be due to performance reasons. I know games need a lot there and it's possible that using normal inheritance is slower. With that said, I am not sure it would be *that* much slower. The pattern here does exist but I agree it's reinventing it. Combining objects together is done via mixins and there are libraries that make it simpler like [stampit](https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit). The combining of methods is slightly odd but not too dissimilar. Still, it seems like something that would be a solved problem at this point.

Comment: @VLAZ -- you might be right. The first thing I thought looking at this is that it might be better to use pure prototype inheritance and `Object.create`, but this particular example make such a very clean class hierarchy that it's too inviting not to at least explore.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm aware that overcharge doesn't exists but what I'm attempting to is neither overload, neither override. Semantically, overcharge looks to be a valid term, note that I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: @user6465431354 the "overcharge" is confusing and also a meaningless term because you've shown standard OO over**riding** in a parent method in a child class but also call the functionality `overLoadMethods `.

Comment: standard overridding isn't the replacement of the parent method ? That's right, my method name is actually inaccurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common Lisp has [something similar](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defmet.htm#defmethod). When you define a method in a derived class you can decide whether this method should be executed:

- `:before` (i.e. the base method will be called automatically after specialized one)
- `:after` (i.e. the base method will be called automatically before the specialized one)
- `:around` (i.e. only the specialized method will be called, but inside its body you can call the base method with `call-next-method` that is a special syntax that allows calling base method with either the parameters specified by the caller or the parameters that you want to pass instead).

For example C++ only has `around` available for general methods (but without the ability to call the base version with original parameters) and forces instead use of `before` in constructor and `after` in destructors.

Comment: That answer leverage something I didn't thought first: arguments

Comment: I accept this method because my question was "why it would be avoided" and this answer say that some more experienced people than me stated it was a good idea and they designed language features for doing it

Comment: @user6465431354: I don't have any real experience using object-oriented features of Common Lisp but sure on paper they seem interesting and the case of "adding" operations to the processing of an existing base method is indeed common. Another part that I found really interesting was the condition system of CL (the problem I always noticed with exceptions is that when you catch them it is already too late) but even about conditions I cannot say I've any real experience of using them in a real world scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the desire to not repeat code and create code that makes it hard to make mistakes and forget things. But you still have code the you need to remember to wire up. For example, instead of calling `Entity.die()` you need to call `overLoadMethods()`. I'm not sure that's an improvement over regular of classes and calling `super.die()`.

You can get the chained method behavior using ES6 classes (you can also get it using prototypes). This has a lot of advantages:

• The pattern is baked into the language.
• It's very clear to see parent/child relationship
• There's a lot of commentary, theory, and examples of different patterns

```js
class Entity {
  die() {
    // Entity-specific behavior
    console.log('entity die')
  }
}

class Body extends Entity {
  die() {
    super.die()
    // Body-specific behavior
    console.log('body die')
  }
}

class Player extends Body {
  die() {
    super.die()
    // Player-specific behavior
    console.log('player die')
  }
}


const player = new Player
// will call Entity.die() then Body.die() then Player.die()
player.die()
```

Comment: I do like this answer - this is the proper OO way of adding more functionality in a subclass. However, I do want to echo the usual "composition over inheritance". Because *this* works but you can easily get into a situation where the abstraction breaks down - you might need a "eatFood" method but then you define a `Robot` child class. It doesn't need to eat food. But it can `shootLasers`. Yet a `JonSkeet` can both eat and shoot lasers but it can't die. Doesn't make this answer *wrong* but it's something to think about when thinking of inheritance and what objects should represent and do.

Comment: In the given exemple, it's much more smart to directly call the parent method but what if there is 10 methods in 4 classes ? 40 occurrences to not forget become 4 occurrences. I like generic because it scales.

Comment: Do you really need a variations of *each method*? If so, it doesn't sound like the base methods are all that useful if each needs to be customised. Although you might derive new ones through functional composition and/or maybe passing a callbacks/options with the extra behaviour.

Comment: I'm not so much into the ES6 classes pattern, I do prefer functions and primitive objects. The use of `this` quickly become a mess with classes with dozens of functions. Separate functions, functional programming with state objects. I not say it's better, just my preference.
But anyway, on this example, you still need to call super for every single method you write, the problem is the same

Comment: @VLAZ yes, each method has to be something fundamentally different than the parent one, but it still the same event (ie. die). All parent classes methods are necessary. The functional composition is something I like but where should I compose my function ? The Player.die will be a composition of `Entity.die` and `Body.die` ? Then I still need to import those functions in my Player right ?
The idea is to keep the code very easy to read, without options and even more without callbacks.